# Increase Azure Media Services SWT Token expiry time

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, video-streaming, azure-media-services

By default in Azure Media Service SWT Token expires after few minutes. That means, video can't be encrypted with that token again. This is great & recommended feature to generate key-token for each playback because keys/token is plain text. But I would like to control this expiry time from code.
For the testing purpose I am using Azure Media Explorer Tools suggested on [Mingfeiy's blog](http://mingfeiy.com/setting-up-playready-encryption-using-azure-media-explorer-tool).

Here is screenshot of this tool which sets end date time and this works great.

[image]

Can you please suggest how to achieve this from code? Here is the code I'll be using to set Issuer and Audience information. I guess there will be some way to setup this as well.

```
    static private string GenerateTokenRequirements()
    {
        Uri _issuer = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Issuer"]);
        Uri _audience = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"]);

        TokenRestrictionTemplate template = new TokenRestrictionTemplate(TokenType.SWT);

        template.PrimaryVerificationKey = new SymmetricVerificationKey();
        template.AlternateVerificationKeys.Add(new SymmetricVerificationKey());
        template.Audience = _issuer.ToString();
        template.Issuer = _audience.ToString();

        // Maybe here            

        template.RequiredClaims.Add(TokenClaim.ContentKeyIdentifierClaim);

        return TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer.Serialize(template);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate token with expiry date with the following method:
 string testToken = TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer.GenerateTestToken(tokenTemplate, null, rawkey, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(365));

The signature of this method is in this source code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/blob/07a536cb1b3f5fb19ac0f25c12c7a360794db7d3/src/net/Client/ContentKeyAuthorization/Templates/TokenRestrictionTemplateSerializer.cs

DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(365) is expiryOn datetime.

Comment: Thanks Mingfei for helping me out always.